# After SDE Conversion, cannot open our GP Services to republish them

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, c#, enterprise-geodatabase, geoprocessing-service

We have several services that were originally published against a local file-based database (with ArcMap 10.1).  We spent the past week converting the data into an SDE database and we are running under Arcmap 10.2.2.  Now it is my turn to convert the services to use the database and get them published to the Arc Server.

All of the internal code just calls one of two methods and those all got changed.
In Arcmap I removed all of the folder shares, renamed the gdb local database to hide it, and pointed Arcmap at the SDE server.  Then I made that database the default.

Next I rebuilt our DLL, reregistered it to the Desktop, deleted all of the old service toolbox entries and recreated them.  I should specify here that almost every one of our services specify schema names in the database for our parameters in the ParameterInfo method.

When I go to publish the services the execute window does not open except for our one service that does not use schema's to define the parameters. The implication is that ArcMap cannot find the schemas in the database.  Yes I've tried with our schema names simple (eg. Simple_Polygon) as well as fully qualified (eg. OurServer.DBO.Simple_Polygon) but neither attempt has been successful.

I cannot see any other thing I need to do in order to get ArcMap to see our schemas so that I can publish the service.  What am I missing???  I cannot find any ESRI documentation that talks about this aspect of publishing a geoprocessing service.

Comment: I removed your [tag:arcgis-publisher] tag because there is nothing in your Question to suggest that you are using the Publisher extension to ArcGIS for Desktop.  On the other hand you seem clearly to be working with ArcGIS for Server and its Geoprocessing Services so I added tags for them.  Can you edit your Question body and tags to include the version (e.g. 10.2 and [tag:arcgis-10.2]) of ArcGIS for Server that you are using, please?

Comment: Have you registered the geodatabase with the Server instance? Without a sample of your connection code it's difficult to tell what may have gone wrong.  Did you enable more detailed logging in the Server site?  What do the logs indicate?  Does your GP app even run successfully in Desktop? This is a prerequisite before you can publish in Server.

Comment: We are never getting the server into the mix because we cannot publish the services to the server.  When we try to bring up the tool for publishing the usual Arcmap execution window with parameters does not open.

Comment: Are you saying the "Service Editor", the window/wizard to publish a service doesn't open? If thats the case, in ArcMap, goto Customize >ArcMap options and on the sharing tab you'll see a "staging path". Go to that directory and delete everything there. Then after restarting ArcMap, try publishing again from a NEW result (fresh tool execution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the issue after quite a bit of digging.  Seems that ESRI, in all their wisdom, needs a unique connection string format.  Once we got all fields supplied and the format they want, the tool windows opened up.  So the connection string format we used was

"Server=sde:sqlserver:{servername};Instance=sde:sqlserver:{servername};Database={database};User={user};Password={pw};DBClient=sqlserver;Authentication_Mode=DBMS"

Apparently you must have instance even if you do not have a named instance AND you need the authentication mode specified.  Those combined eliminate the login window AND gave me access to the schemas when I opened the tool.